# Remove a File Navigation View from the Intellij IDEA IDE Editor

Tags: android, user-interface, intellij-idea, navigation

The view I have circled in the image is used to navigate through the files but it takes up too much space whe I have too many files and tabs open.

I don't know it's name so I can't Google.

I would like to remove it.

[image: A sample image of my IDE]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin name is called **CodeGlance**.